# Ant Get task Timeout issue

Tags: ant, get, task

I have a web service that returns a plain text. I am going to add timeout that if the service is not up set a property to true. How can I do that? Below is my code.

```
<get src="localhost:8080/order/available" dest="${propertyname}"/>
```

---

I am getting:

**get doesn't support the "maxtime" attribute**

Answer (score 3):

You can use something like this.  First download to a file, then check if the file is there:

```
<delete file="${testfile}"/>
<get src="localhost:8080/order/available" dest="${testfile}" maxtime="5000" />
<available file="${testfile}"  property="${propertyname}" value="true"/>
```

EDIT: The maxtime attribute is available in ant 1.8.0 or higher as per their [doc](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/get.html)

Comment: I am getting:get doesn't support the "maxtime" attribute